# How to get all records if nested records do not exist in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I want to get all parent records if the child does not exist on Sequelize, like the one below codes get all the records with if nested records

```
const posts = await Post.findAll({
    order: [
        ['createdAt', 'DESC']
    ],
    include: [{
        model: db.replies, as: 'replies',
        createdAt: 'DESC'
    }]
})
```

the above codes get all the data from `Post` whether if `replies` exists or not, but for a reason, I want to get all `posts` which do not any `replies` which means not exist the child records.

How could I achieve that, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can reference to nested model's column from parent model's "where" object using syntax like this: "$AssociatedTableName.columnName$"

try  to add:

```
where: {
          '$replies.id$': null 
        },
```

and `required: false`

the resut will be:

```
const posts = await Post.findAll({
 where: {
          '$replies.id$': null 
        },
    order: [
        ['createdAt', 'DESC']
    ],
    include: [{
        model: db.replies, as: 'replies',
        createdAt: 'DESC',
        required: false
    }]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

u can create use a literal method

from sequelize.literal, is the raw SQL. i.e

to consider Order and OrderDetail is the order_detail table.

You exclude the all orders that havent details in this case.

```js
const orders = await Order.findAll({
     where: {
        ...where,
        [Op.all]: literal(
           "0 = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM order_detail WHERE id_order `Order`.`id_order`)"
        ),
     },
     attributes: [...listOfAttibutes ], 
     include: []
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need two things:

1. Add an outer join, which will keep the parent records without any associated child.
2. `where` clause that filters out the parent records that has associated child

Here is complete query:

```
const posts = await Post.findAll({
  where: {
    // 2. This will filter out any posts that have replies
    '$replies.id$': {
      [Op.eq]: null
    }
  },
  include: [
    {
      model: db.replies,
      as: 'replies',
      required: false // 1. This will make the join left outer
    }
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write you code like as below.

```
Post.findAll({
  where: {
    id: {
      [Sequelize.Op.notIn]: sequelize.literal(
        `(SELECT userId FROM replies)`
      )
    }
  }
})

or

Post.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: Reply,
      attributes: []
    }
  ],
  where: {
    '$Replies.id$': null // Filter out posts with associated replies
  }
})
```